# 'Contains' Filter with TextBox as User Input

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I'm guessing this is simple but I'm struggling to find a proper solution to this.

I require to use the 'Contains' filter with a TextBox as the user input.
Eg: User types in "Hello" in the TextBox and results returned are "Hello USA", "Hello Buddy", "Hello" etc.

The piece of code which I'm stuck with

```
 Selection.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=UserForm1.TextBox1.Value, Operator:=xlOr
```

Right now it just gives me cells with the exact word in it.
Could anyone point me in the right direction or a tutorial link.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4):

When in doubt, record a macro using the macro recorder. Which will give you:

```
Selection.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=Hello*", Operator:=xlAnd
```

Therefore,

```
Selection.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=" & UserForm1.TextBox1.Value & "*", Operator:=xlAnd
```